# Exception when i try to update .properties file

Tags: java

In servlet, I am getting the values from form and trying to update properties file value with form values. But I am getting the `java.io.IOException`. Please tell me how to overcome this issue and update my properties file. If I update the properties file will I be able to see the changes in .properties file.
Servlet

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name=request.getParameter("appName");
    String link=request.getParameter("appLink");
    String database=request.getParameter("appDB");
    String webServices=request.getParameter("appWebService");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("server_url.properties");
    in.close();
    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("server_url.properties");
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_Links", link);
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_DataBase", database);
    props.store(outputStream , null);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
System.out.println(link);
System.out.println(database);
}
```

Stack trace

```
java.io.IOException: Stream Closed
java.io.FileInputStream.readBytes(Native Method)
java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:243)
java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Properties.java:434)
java.util.Properties.load0(Properties.java:353)
java.util.Properties.load(Properties.java:341)
com.monitoring.servlets.updateDetails.doPost(updateDetails.java:38)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:641)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
```

Comment: Not sure if this is your error, but are you sure you should be using a closed `FileInputStream` when calling `load`?

Comment: Check the stacktrace 1. java.io.IOException: Stream Closed 2.com.monitoring.servlets.updateDetails.doPost(updateDetails.java:38)

Comment: @TNT  I removed close().. I am not getting that exception now. But the update is not getting reflected in my .properties file.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at stack trace `java.io.IOException: Stream Closed`, Seems like problem is with your `FileInputStream` close statement in wrong place.
You are closing it first `in.close()` and then you are reading it in the next statement `props.load(in)`.

Try writing `in.close()` statement at last.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is you are closing the stream(`in.close();`) and after that you are loading it(`props.load(in);`)

Best practice is to close at the end

```
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String name=request.getParameter("appName");
    String link=request.getParameter("appLink");
    String database=request.getParameter("appDB");
    String webServices=request.getParameter("appWebService");
    FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream("server_url.properties");

    Properties props = new Properties();
    props.load(in);
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("server_url.properties");
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_Links", link);
    props.setProperty("DemoApps_DataBase", database);
    props.store(outputStream , null);
    outputStream.flush();
    outputStream.close();
System.out.println(link);
System.out.println(database);
in.close();
}
```